# neo4j invalid syntax in conditional

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to delete node if the node has no relationshops and return true, otherwise return false

```
match (p:Type {id:72})-->(x)
RETURN 
CASE count(x)
WHEN 0 THEN DELETE p 'true'
ELSE 'false'
END AS deleted;
```

i always get invalid syntax. Is this possible in cypher?

Comment: case is just a compute expression not a conditional clause

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
match (p:Type {id:72})
where not exists ((p)--())
delete p
```

Answer (score 0):

To find nodes having no relationships you need to use `OPTIONAL MATCH` and check for null after a `WITH`:

```
match (p:Type {id:72})
optional match (p)-[r]-()
with p, r
where r IS null
delete p
```